# Image preview works on ie 11 on some computers but not on others

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have javascript code that displays an image preview when you select an image to submit. The problem is that it works fine on IE 11 on a couple of machines but not on IE 11 on other machines. It seems to me that there are browser setting differences between the machines - I checked that the following are same across the machines:

1. Enable active scripting on security settings
2. Allow scripting on java applets on security settings
3. Enable show pictures
4. Added the site to trusted sites
5. Removed the site from compatibility view settings

My javascript:

```
<script>
function readURL(input) {

if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        document.getElementById('imageId').setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
        setDataChanged();
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
}
</script>
```

My html:

```
<td rowspan="4">
    <html:file property="formFile" size="60" styleId="importFile" accept="image/jpeg" style="visibility:hidden" onchange="readURL(this)"/>
    <img id="imageId" src="<c:out value="${imageContentValue}"/>" width="130" height="130" onclick="document.getElementById('importFile').click();" onchange="setDataChanged();"/>
</td>
```

Appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Comment: Check the browsers if they support filereader.  Cant really help you otherwise.  Or just inform the user that they are using a cadaver to browse the internet.

Comment: Do you have access to a machine that works, as well as a machine that does not work? If so, what - if any - output do you see in the developer console? Press F12 to reveal the console, and refresh the page to see if any errors appear.

Comment: Thank you Sampson - I have been able to resolve my issue by checking the developer console as you suggested. The console indicated that the page was open in compatibility view mode because 'Display intranet sites in compatibility view' was enabled. Once i unchecked the same, image preview started working on those machines as well :)